# Can space have angular momentum that can be transfered to/from physical objects?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, angular-momentum

This is related to [another question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/can-space-time-itself-have-energy-qualities-like-momentum) that discusses whether space can have momentum and energy. Apparently gravitational waves or ripples in spacetime is how space stores and transfers energy/momentum.

Assume that space has two only two spheres with masses $m_0$ and $m_1$. If sphere with mass $m_0$ is suddenly imparted a rotation of velocity $\omega$, will the rotation somehow flow to the other sphere so that both rotate? If so, will both rotate in the same direction to ensure that the overall angular momentum is $m_0\omega$ or will they be opposed to make the overall angular momentum 0?

Answer (score 2):

Comments to the question (v1):

1. In Newtonian mechanics with Newtonian gravity, a body can have orbital angular momentum wrt. a reference frame. A non-point-mass can also have spin angular momentum. Bodies can exchange angular momentum via tidal forces.
2. In [GR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity), it possible to assign angular momentum to certain space-time regions (such as e.g. the [Kerr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) space-times) and exchange angular momentum with e.g. matter test probes.
3. Finally, let us mention [gravitoelectromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism), which is an approximation to GR. Here the [EFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) takes the form of [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations), and a spin angular momentum plays the role of a magnetic dipole moment.

Comment: Any comments on the rotating mass question?